# What is nicetec-mgmt on port 2557?

Tags: networking, port, wireshark

I've been looking at wireshark, and have a lot of UDP traffic to port 2557 (from 25322), the port is reportedly used for nicetec-mgmt, does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably actually another service, application, or process rather than nicetec-mgmt (whatever that is). I would recommend either of the following two things:

1. Find the computer where this traffic is originating from and install Microsoft Network Monitor and start a capture.
2. Find the computer where this traffic is destined and install Microsoft Network Monitor and start a capture.

MS NetMon has an option to show the process responsible for the traffic so either one of these should help you narrow down what's responsible for this traffic.

Comment: I like the idea, so tried to give it a go but I can't see how to bind the network adapter to the netmon driver - I can see where I am supposed to do it, but there aren't any network adapters there. If I press start, there is just a msg that says I may need to log out and back in. I didn't this, nothing changed.

Comment: NetMon should bind it's driver to the NIC automatically during install. Check to see if it's listed as a component on the NIC and if so, if it's enabled (checked). Try a reboot for good measure but I haven't seen the install ever require a reboot.

Comment: How do I check if it is listed as a component on the NIC, do you mean to do this in NetMon?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the NIC, on the General tab you should see a component called "Network Monitor Driver". It should be checked. Then in the NetMon application, in the lower left corner you should see a pane titled "Select Networks", there you want to select the NIC that you want to capture from, then click the "New Capture" button on the tool bar, then click the "Start" button on the capture window tool bar.